# static.php running multiple instances and hitting 100% cpu

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cron

I've recently installed, then uninstalled the Simplify Magento Module after some issues started cropping up.

Now the site hits 100% CPU whenever I load just the homepage. Still on testing environment, so no users yet.

This is what I see when I look at the open processes -

`[testsite@s321 stage]$ ps -eo pid,ppid,%cpu,start_time,command
    PID    PPID %CPU START COMMAND
 951027  951026  0.0 10:18 -bash
 953335  840583  0.0 10:21 lsphp
 955942  953335 28.3 10:24 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 956972  953335 31.2 10:25 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 957256  953335 29.5 10:25 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 958087  958054  0.0 10:27 /bin/sh -c /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/testsite/public_html/stage/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep
 958095  958087  0.0 10:27 grep -v Ran jobs by schedule
 958760       1 25.7 10:27 /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/testsite/public_html/stage/bin/magento cron:run --group=consumers --bo
 958763       1 27.2 10:27 /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/testsite/public_html/stage/bin/magento cron:run --group=index --bootst
 958765       1 20.5 10:27 /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/testsite/public_html/stage/bin/magento cron:run --group=ddg_automation
 958848  958819  0.0 10:28 /bin/sh -c /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/testsite/public_html/stage/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep
 958853  958848 20.6 10:28 /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/testsite/public_html/stage/bin/magento cron:run
 958854  958848  0.0 10:28 grep -v Ran jobs by schedule
 959189  953335  8.7 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959190  953335 15.1 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959191  953335 16.2 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959192  953335  5.6 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959193  953335  7.8 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959194  953335  5.4 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959195  953335  4.3 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959196  953335  4.2 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959197  953335  4.2 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959198  953335  5.6 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959199  953335  5.6 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959200  953335  9.5 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959201  953335  6.7 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959202  953335 12.5 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959203  953335  6.3 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959204  953335  6.1 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959205  953335  5.8 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959206  953335  3.4 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959207  953335  5.4 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959208  953335 11.6 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959209  953335 13.5 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959210  953335  7.5 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959211  953335  6.1 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959212  953335 11.9 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959213  953335  7.1 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959214  953335  3.4 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959217  953335  6.1 10:28 lsphp:ome/testsite/public_html/stage/pub/static.php
 959234  953335  5.5 10:28 lsphp:/home/testsite/public_html/stage/index.php
 959401  951027  0.0 10:28 ps -eo pid,ppid,%cpu,start_time,command`

Things that I've tried -

- removing pub/static
- removing var/pre_processed
- disabling all cron jobs
- emptying the cron table

Not sure what else I can try to resolve this. Currently only on a test server, so all the processes above are just from me hitting the homepage.